# HttpContext.Current is null after Task.Run

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, task

Here are my project details

1. A web-API project containing webapi controllers
2. I have a separate c# Library project that contains models for my webapi and some method and api for intracting with database.

**settings in webconfig**

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
```

**Issue**: HttpContext.Current.user is null.I want to access Httpcontext.Current.user in my c# library project.

1.In the code snippet below  HttpContext.Current.user is available.This method exist in webapi project.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]TEntity entity)
        {
            System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

            // context is available till here
            var context =HttpContext.Current.User;

            return await Task<IHttpActionResult>.Run(() =>
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return (IHttpActionResult)Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState.ToUnexpectedResultWrapper());
                }

                try
                {
                    TOrchestrator orchestrator = new TOrchestrator();
                    orchestrator.Insert(entity);
                }
                catch (ValidationException ex)
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.ToUnexpectedResultWrapper());
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.ToUnexpectedResultWrapper());
                }

                return CreatedAtRoute("REST", new { id = entity.Id }, entity);
            });

        }
```

2.In code snippet below that exist in C# library. HttContext.Current.user is null. this method is called from the above method "Post".

```
 public void Insert(Market market)
            {
                // Context is 
                System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                //IOATIApplicationUser user = UserContextHelper.GetOATIContext().OATIUser;
                var http = HttpContext.Current.User;
                RunAction<InsertAction, Market>(market);
            }
```

More over I could access user object from System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

If I cant access user object from HttpContext. Can i user System> System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal. I have heard it is not safe to user "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal" and it is ment for window forms only.

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` gets the user the site is running as, which is often not the actual user that's accessing the site. Instead of using `HttpContext.Current` to get your data, why not pass it into your `Insert` method as a parameter? Libraries should often NOT depend on having an `HttpContext` available and should receive the required info via parameters in order to keep the code portable.

Answer (score 3):

`HttpContext.Current` returns the *current `HttpContext` being serviced by the calling thread*. When you start a background task by using `Task.Run`, it is not associated with an HTTP context *by design*.

Since you should not be using `Task.Run` on ASP.NET anyway, removing it is the easiest solution:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]TEntity entity)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return (IHttpActionResult)Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState.ToUnexpectedResultWrapper());
  }

  try
  {
    TOrchestrator orchestrator = new TOrchestrator();
    orchestrator.Insert(entity);
  }
  catch (ValidationException ex)
  {
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.ToUnexpectedResultWrapper());
  }
  catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
  {
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.ToUnexpectedResultWrapper());
  }

  return CreatedAtRoute("REST", new { id = entity.Id }, entity);
}
```

Comment: Stephen thanks for replying. we   are developing a framework and we need to expose current principal which is available  in all the threads. Above code snippet is from  application team.We may not be able to change there implmentation. .So can we use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Value of principal is not null even in Task.Run.

Comment: @harmeet: If your framework needs to expose context, I recommend doing so through an actual *context instance*, not any kind of TLS or ambient state. But if you must, then `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` should work.

Comment: I  didnt get what you meant by TLS or ambient state.My only objective is that if I access Thread,currentPrincipal should return principal that is currently logged in users principal.

Comment: @harmeet: TLS is thread-local storage. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is stored as TLS. The whole question is around how the "currently" works in "currently logged in" - is the login/context/session an actual *object instance* (which IMO is a cleaner design), or do you really want it to be a magical invocation (`Thread.CurrentPrincipal`) that returns different values when accessed by different threads?